# query with max value not get one row

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where I would like to get a row of a max value with a where.
I'm trying to do:

```
select max(version) as max, curr_ver, creation_date, nameJob  from schema.def where nameJob = 'try'
group by curr_ver,creation_date,nameJob;
```

I get:

```
VERSION  CREATION_DATE  NAMEJOB CURR_VER
-------  -------------- -------- ---------
2        20180301       TRY      N
1        20180307       TRY      Y
```

I only would like to get (max row)

```
VERSION  CREATION_DATE  NAMEJOB CURR_VER
-------  -------------- -------- ---------
2        20180301       TRY      N
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: You get 2 records because of `creation_date` in your group by clause. This is bringing the max for each date. The result is correct as per your query.

Comment: This is not a pl/sql question. please fix your tags put  `sql` , `oralce` instead  (if you use oracle)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `row` that has a `max` value of your group max values then, something like this would do:

```
select max(version) as max, curr_ver, creation_date, nameJob  
from schema.def 
where nameJob = 'try'
group by curr_ver,creation_date,nameJob
having 
max(version) = (select max(version) as global_max from schema.def 
where nameJob = 'try');
```